# SwiftUI FocusState not working in popover

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I would like to activate textfield with keyboard when popover appears, same as a user tap, but while working in a regular view, the following code does not work when presented in popover.

Any solutions? Thank you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var str = ""
    @State var show = false
    
    @FocusState private var focused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Popover")
                .onTapGesture {
                    show.toggle()
                }
                .popover(isPresented: $show) {
                    TextField("Popover Textfield", text: $str)
                        .focused($focused)
                        .onAppear {
                            focused = true
                        }
                }
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@FocusState is bounded to the root view, just split it like so:

```
struct focusText: View {
    @State var str = ""
    @State var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Popover")
                .onTapGesture {
                    show.toggle()
                }
                .popover(isPresented: $show) {
                    popView(str: $str)
                }
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}

struct popView: View {
    @Binding var str: String
    @FocusState private var focused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Popover Textfield", text: $str)
                .focused($focused)
        }
        .onAppear {
            focused = true
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that by default the simulator does not show the keyboard.

[image]